# file I/O java absolute vs. relative file name

Tags: java

For File I/O. We were told to use relative file name vs. absolute file name. So my question is Why is it better to use the relative file name rather than the absolute?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute filename is platform dependent whereas the relative one just points from the folder you're in.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it better to use the relative file name rather than the absolute?

It depends on what you are actually doing.  In fact, for some purposes absolute paths are better than relative paths.

The main advantage of an absolute path is that it always means the same thing.

The main disadvantage of an absolute path is that if you move a file (or tree) you change its absolute path.  If you previous saved the location of some file as an absolute path, you now have to change it.

The advantages of relative paths are

- that they are shorter,
- they are generally more user friendly, and
- they can<sup>1</sup> make it easier to deal with collections of files that have moved.

But the disadvantage is that a relative path (at least in Java with a `File` object) is *resolved* relative to the JVM's *current directory*.  In a lot of situations there is uncertainty (in the mind of the user and/or developer) over what it actually is.  And if it is not what you expect, a relative path with resolve incorrectly.

---

<sup>1 - The caveat is that you are actually relying on the JVM being *launched* with the appropriate *current directory*.  Once the JVM has launched, it cannot change its current directory.  Or at least, you can't do it in pure Java ... AFAIK.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you move your project to another system there are two kinds of problems you could run into with absolute paths:

1. The resources may reside at different places in the file system
2. You may be using a different *kind* of operating system (e.g. Windows vs. Linux/Unix). Those systems use totally different kinds of path descriptors.